# Jquery select children without class like

Tags: jquery

I know I'm close, but need a hint here! I'm trying to select data from certain class elements contained insider other elements based on whether a specific parent has a tag in the class name or not.

```
<div class=something_1>
<div class=other>
<div class=other>
<div class=other_TEMPLATE_1>
<div class=other>
<div class=selected_thing>I DO NOT WANT THIS</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class=something_2>
<div class=other>
<div class=other>
<div class=other_TEMPLATE_2>
<div class=other>
<div class=selected_thing>I DO NOT WANT THIS</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class=something_3>
<div class=other>
<div class=other>
<div class=other>
<div class=other>
<div class=selected_thing>I WANT THIS</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>

$("[class^=something]").each(function(){

selectedThing = $(this).children().children().children(":not[class^=other_TEMPLATE]").children().children(".selected_thing").html();

console.log(selectedThing);

});

</script>
```

As you can see part of the challenge is that some of the class names can change slightly but I'm wanting to ignore those where TEMPLATE shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$('.selected_thing').each(function(){
    if($(this).parents('[class*="TEMPLATE"]').length==0){
    //do something
        $(this).css('color','red')
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6h9Nx/)**

Comment: Nice and clean solution, go with this!

Comment: Perfect - a much better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[class^=something]").each(function(){

selectedThing = $(this).find('div').not("[class^=other_TEMPLATE]").children().children(".selected_thing").html();

console.log(selectedThing);

});
```

Comment: LOL looks like we wrote the exact same selector?! You were faster than me though... :(

Comment: Yes, but, - j08691 wins, i think. :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedThings = [];

$("[class^=something]").each(function(){

selected = $(this).find('div')
.not("[class^=other_TEMPLATE]")
.children().children(".selected_thing")
.html();

if(selected !== undefined)
{
    selectedThings.push(selected);
}

});

console.log(selectedThings);
```

EDIT: To slow :( @nevermind won...

Answer (score 1):

`$('.selected_thing').not('[class*="TEMPLATE"] .selected_thing');`

[Accompanying JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_sir/yZ9e5/)